# Everytime I call my updateScore() method, it won't update the score?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to update my score everytime I call the method "updateScore()" but for some reason it doesn't work.

if I win the first time, it will update it properly, then if I select a new game and win, it won't update the score, the score remains like it is.

**Example**

first win---> (X) Wins: 1

second win--->(X) Wins: 1 ????? it should be 2

.

**CODE SOURCE**

```
public void updateScore() {
    xWinnerTimes = 0;
    oWinnerTimes = 0;
    winnerBoardO = findViewById(R.id.winner_o);
    winnerBoardX = findViewById(R.id.winner_x);
    if (winner == 1){
        xWinnerTimes++;
        winnerBoardX.setText("(X) Wins: " + (xWinnerTimes));
    }

    if (winner ==2){
        oWinnerTimes++;
        winnerBoardO.setText("(O) Wins: " + (oWinnerTimes));
    }
```

Comment: Debug your code ..

Comment: What you want exactly?? can you please elebrote? mention whole class code if you don't mind.

Comment: @ADM i did debug my code, the "oWinnerTimes" isn't incrementing I'm not sure why. i looked over my other methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mention below code in onCreate Method

```
xWinnerTimes = 0;
oWinnerTimes = 0;
winnerBoardO = findViewById(R.id.winner_o);
winnerBoardX = findViewById(R.id.winner_x);
```

xWinnerTimes  and oWinnerTimes  should be global variable.

and According to me, if you update score on User Interface on a particular time then you have to call your method that is **updateScore()** in **runOnUiThread**

Comment: It works! but only needs one more thing, is that it updates the score by twos? why is that xd

Comment: Can you please post your full code. then i rectify your problem as well as what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `xWinnerTimes = 0;
    oWinnerTimes = 0;` in global and remove it in updateScore(); Because you always reset it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the initialization and incrementation both are in the same scope.
The first time it will show the correct result but next time value again get initialized by 0.
Try to make that variable global
Declare them outside from your method.